# ref cursor in for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, ref-cursor

Is ref cursor can be used in for loop like cursors?  i.e. like

```
for i in cur_name 
loop
dbms_output.put_line(i.column_name)
end loop;
```

If not possible then why?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? By the way, yes it is possible. But it really makes no sense. See https://community.oracle.com/thread/2451436?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not use `for` loop just as you do against an `implicit/explicit cursors`

```
declare
    ref_cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN ref_cur FOR SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE ROWNUM < 5;
    for i in ref_cur loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i.table_name); 
    end loop;  
END;
/
```

you will get an error

> PLS-00221: 'REF_CUR' is not a procedure or is undefined

A `ref cursor` being a pointer to an `open cursor` used to send an open cursor as an out argument to the client app to loop through the record.
If you want to loop through then,

```
declare
    ref_cur sys_refcursor;
    v_name all_tables.table_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN ref_cur FOR SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE ROWNUM < 5;
    LOOP
        FETCH  ref_cur INTO  v_name;
        exit when ref_cur%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_name); 
    end loop;  
END;
/
```

You can use `implicit/explicit cursors` if the life time of the cursor is with in the `*block*`

```
declare
    cursor cur IS SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE ROWNUM < 5;
BEGIN 
    for i in cur loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i.table_name); 
    end loop;
END;
/
```

or

```
BEGIN 
    for i in (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE ROWNUM < 5) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i.table_name); 
    end loop;
END;
/
```